# How to call a child function inside a function from another function in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, function

```
function Hello()
{
  function HelloAgain(){
  }
}

function MyFunction(){
...
}
```

Here I need to call the function HelloAgain() from MyFunction().
Can you suggest any possible solution for this scenario.

Comment: Is google down?

Comment: If `HelloAgain` is nested, it suggests that it shouldn't be used from outside the parent function. Why nest it in the first place if you need it outside of the function. And I don't think this would logically make sense. What if the child function used data from the parent function? If the parent function was never called, what data would the inner function use?

Comment: That is sort of impossible.... unless you somehow expose it.

Comment: @VedPrakash are you sure about that duplicate? Both functions look top level, but in this question there is one nested function.

Comment: How about return object from first function and inner function as method https://jsfiddle.net/Lg0wyt9u/2089/

Comment: @yuriy636 Same logic applied in the both question.

Comment: Funny thing. I just googled this AND THIS NON-ANSWER COMES UP

Answer (score 1):

You can't, the HelloAgain function is in a closure and is scoped to that closure.

You could return the HelloAgain function and then call it from anywhere you can call Hello.

```
function Hello () {
  function HelloAgain () {}
  return HelloAgain;
}

function MyFunction () {
  Hello().HelloAgain();
}
```

But that slightly weird.

More over you could use the `this` keyword to deal with the matter.

```
function Hello () {
  this.helloAgain = function helloAgain () {}
}

var hello = new Hello();

function MyFunction () {
  hello.helloAgain();
}
```

Comment: Please explain that `this` will be `window` in that context (thus making `helloagain` a global variable), saying "you can use `this` to deal with the matter" is a little bit obscure.

Comment: `this` is in the conext `Hello` not `window` https://jsfiddle.net/L09y3gcL/

Comment: True, sorry, totally missed the `new Hello()` part.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. The scope of `HelloAgain` il limited to the `Hello` function. 
This is the only way to make private scope in javascript.